# Unicode encoding in php with Hebrew

Tags: php, encoding

i am trying to get some information from a webpage however it is in a different encoding is there an easy way to convert to utf8 and then use it?

For example i am getting these urls which i will need to visit

```
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1496;&#1493;&#1508;&#1493;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1490;&#1489;&#1497;&#1504;&#1492;_&#1502;&#1500;&#1493;&#1495;&#1492;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1490;&#1489;&#1497;&#1504;&#1492;_&#1500;&#1488;&#1512;&#1493;&#1495;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1490;&#1489;&#1497;&#1504;&#1492;_&#1502;&#1493;&#1514;&#1499;&#1514;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1490;&#1489;&#1497;&#1504;&#1492;_&#1510;&#1492;&#1493;&#1489;&#1492;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1490;&#1489;&#1497;&#1504;&#1492;_&#1500;&#1489;&#1504;&#1492;/
http://www.mega.co.il/jsfweb/cat/&#1511;&#1493;&#1496;&#1490;/
```

how do i turn that to utf8 and then urlencode in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try function [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to decode that entities. To change decoding, use [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). I have no experience with Hebrew, so I don't know if it would work.